# How do i make sure all the data from database won't disappear after i delete the existing folder of woocommerce plugin?

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce, delete-file, exists

This is the error that I get in WordPress

"YITH WooCommerce Wishlist is enabled but not effective. It requires WooCommerce to work.
.
.
Destination folder already exists....../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/"

The problem is that the woo-commerce plugin does not exist in WordPress, however, the physical file in Cpanel exists. I wonder if I delete the file I could still save the data within it.

Comment: Are there data within the woocommerce folder?

Comment: yes, there's data in the folder

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of the woocommerce folder and then try removing it, and check YITH WooCommerce Wishlist, I hope you have uploaded woo folder through ftp.
Backup will not let your data lost.

Comment: backup using the WordPress plugin?